# RestSharp v107: setting Json serialization options

Tags: c#, restsharp, system.text.json

I'm using the new `RestSharp v107`, which started using the `System.Text.Json` classes to manage JSON (de)serialization.

This being the case, I thought we would be able to provide our own instance of `JsonSerializerOptions` to customize how serialization is handled, however I cannot see any settings in the `RestClientOptions` object to set the json serialization options. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out the answer shortly after posting.

All you have to do is:

```
httpClient.UseSystemTextJson(new JsonSerializerOptions() { ... });
```

and it's done, simple as that

Comment: Definitely, this bit was missing in the docs, I added it now.

Comment: "JsonSerializerOptions" can be found at namespace "System.Text.Json"

Comment: as of version 106.15.0, this seem to no longer work.

Comment: @brando: not "no longer", but "not yet". As you can see from the title, this question is about RestSharp v107+, which started using System.Text.Json. Previous versions like the v106.xx that you mention did not user System.Text.Json at all, so this question is not relevant to your situation.

Comment: Have version 110, didn't have UseSystemTextJson method on restclient object.

Answer (score 2):

With version 110, you have to add the serialization configuration in the RestClient constructor

```
var client = new RestClient(
   options, 
   configureSerialization: s => s.UseSystemTextJson(new JsonSerializerOptions {...})
);
```